# Obj-c - App crashes when grabbing value from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to print node_title value from my NSDictionary (self.acceptedFriends) in an NSString, but for some reason my app crashes with the error ***'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17400fa60'*** when I use the following line of code:

**ViewController.m**

`NSString *test = self.acceptedFriends[@"node_title"][0];`

See returned structure below. What should the line above actually look like in order to avoid the crash?? I feel like I've tried everything.

**Structure:**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [node_title] => hi
                [body] => jfkmcc
    
                [friendphoto] => /stored/1504111984.jpg
                [uid] => 47
                [address2] => fake street
                [star rating] => 5
                [uid2] => 202
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: What is `self.acceptedFriends` ? Is it NSArray ?

Answer (score 3):

You shoud try

```
 NSString *test = self.acceptedFriends[0][@"node_title"];
```

instead.

Comment: [0] can't go before [@"node_title"] with self.acceptedFriends as an NSDictionary

Comment: Yeah but your "Structure" clearly shows that your self.acceptedFriends is actually an `NSArray`. How are you populating self.acceptedFriends anyway?

Comment: Data from a previous controller (UserViewController) pushes data to the NSDictionary self.acceptedFriends in ViewController. Any way I can convert this to an NSArray in ViewController.m?

Comment: Then you need to show us the code in UserViewController. That's where the bug is.

Comment: @Brittany - as @Yuji stated, `acceptedFriends` is a `NSArray`. There's also no reason to call `[0]` after `[@"node_title"]`, since the value for that is clearly a `NSString`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert `NSDictionary` to `NSArray` and fetch like this way..

```
NSArray *values = [yourResponseDictionary allValues];
NSString *test = values[0][@"node_title"];
```

Comment: yes that's why i am saying to convert into `NSArray`

Comment: as @Yuji says your "Structure" clearly shows that your self.acceptedFriends is actually an `NSArray` so you need to convert in `NSArray`

Comment: I'm wondering how I would convert it to an NSArray ? I thought  NSArray *keys = [self.acceptedFriends allKeys];  NSString *friendsList = keys[0][@"node_title"]; might do it, but no dice...

Comment: @Brittany i think you should copy the **values** instead of keys than you can easily access.
`NSArray *values = [yourResponseDictionary allValues];`
now you can access with values [0]
i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If `self.acceptedFriends` is an `NSArray` then you need to convert using below code

```
 NSArray *nodeTitlesArray = self.acceptedFriends
```

You can access title with below code:

```
NSDictionary *nodeInfo =  [nodeTitlesArray objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *test=  [nodeInfo objectForKey:@"node_title"]
```